# How do I add filenames to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, loops

I created a series of *.txt file using the for loop. But now I want to write the file names in a list. But only the last file name is getting printed in the list and the before ones gets deleted.

```py
for i in range(3):
    i += 0
    new_file = str(i) + ".txt"
    file_list = []        
    file_list.append(new_file)

    with open(new_file, "w") as outfile:
        print("File created...")
print(file_list)
```

The output I am getting is **['2.txt']** 
I need the output to be **['0.txt', '1.txt', '2.txt']**

Comment: Your declaring your list in the loop. This will delete the list every loop. Also, your incrementer is not doing anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python For Loop Appending Only Last Value to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784325/python-for-loop-appending-only-last-value-to-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating your list at each iteration.
You should define your list before the loop:

```
file_list = []  
for i in range(3):
    i += 0
    new_file = str(i) + ".txt"      
    file_list.append(new_file)

    with open(new_file, "w") as outfile:
        print("File created...")
print(file_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are re-initializing the `file_list` in each iteration of the loop. Move that part outside like so:

```
file_list = []        
for i in range(3):
    i += 0
    new_file = str(i) + ".txt"
    file_list.append(new_file)

    with open(new_file, "w") as outfile:
        print("File created...")
print(file_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fourth line of your code, you're setting file_list equal to an empty list. Since this is in your loop, it's happening every time that the loop iterates! If you declare the file_list variable and set it to your starting empty list before your for loop, you should get your expected result.